# how to make a column with autogenerated values using php and oracle database

Tags: php, database, oracle

i have a table of name 'stock' in oracle database and i have columns 'item', 'company', 'purchase', 'sale' and so on. i am using php to make a form and insert values through this form in oracle database. its like this
'item' 'company' 'purchase' 'sale'
purse    abc       200        230
vallet   def       100         120

what i want is to have a column 'id' which should auto generate value when i insert a new row like this
'ID'(auto generated)    'item'      'company'   'purchase'     'sale'
  1                     purse          abc       200            230
  2                     vallet         def       100            120
  3                     vallet         def       50            120
  4                     vallet         def       70            120
please help me. kind regards

Comment: Google for `SEQUENCE` object in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is sequence. It's a thing in Oracle DB for creation auto incrementing numbers.
And [that's](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314) how they are created.
But then you need to link it to your column. You should create the trigger like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tableIdTrigger
  BEFORE INSERT ON tabname FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    SELECT seqname.NEXTVAL into :NEW.id FROM DUAL;
  END tableIdTrigger;
/
```

Comment: Support for "identity" columns (autoincrement to everyone else :-) has been added to Oracle in version 12c. A good description of how this new feature works can be found at [Oracle-Base](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1.php). Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you'll need to create a sequence and then use an INSERT trigger to obtain a value from the sequence and populate the ID column in the table, as in:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE STOCK_ID_SEQ;

CREATE TRIGGER STOCK_BEFORE_INSERT_TRIGGER
  BEFORE INSERT ON STOCK
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.ID IS NULL THEN
    :NEW.ID := STOCK_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
  END IF;
END STOCK_BEFORE_INSERT_TRIGGER;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: can't there be any way in which i use some code in php which then lead to a number that could be save in oracle db

Comment: I can't think of reliable way of doing this from a PHP form, but perhaps some of the PHP experts have something they can offer. In an Oracle DB through version 11 the use of a sequence is the accepted method used to solve this type of problem. Is there some reason you can't use this?

Comment: yes, the only reason i am not using sequence is that i am new to oracle an really don't know what sequence is, how to generate ot how to make it work or connect to php coding... zero idea about it...

Comment: @AlexZam's answer should get you going. Creating the sequence is pretty easy: `CREATE SEQUENCE SOME_SEQUENCE;` is all it takes, where `SOME_SEQUENCE` is the name that you want to use for your sequence. Then use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, as shown by Alex (below), to assign values from the sequence to the column. (As an alternative to the `SELECT SOME_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL...` shown by Alex you can use `:NEW.id := SOME_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL;` to assign the sequence value to the ID column on any Oracle version since v10). Post another question if you need further help. Share and enjoy.

Comment: thnx AlexZam'and Bob Jarvis... m working on it... hope will get what i want. thnx again for help